# Hyper-v issue Event ID4625. Hype-v Cluster

Tags: windows, hyper-v, cluster, microsoft

I have an issue with event id 4625. Hope you can help me to fix it.
I have a Hyper V Cluster whit 6 hosts(2016). On several of my hosts every day I am found alert "Security-Event ID: 4625".
Sometimes the "Source Network Address:" is one of my nodes, and sometimes null.

Example:

*Problem started at 19:30:14 on 2021.10.16

Problem name: Event ID4625 alert - Logon Failure

Severity: High 

Operational data: An account failed to log on.

Subject:

Security ID: S-1-0-0

Account Name: -

Account Domain: -

Logon ID: 0x0

Logon Type: 3

Account For Which Logon Failed:

Security ID: S-1-0-0

Account Name:

Account Domain:

Failure Information:

Failure Reason: An Error occured during Logon.

Status: 0x80090308

Sub Status: 0x0

Process Information:

Caller Process ID: 0x0

Caller Process Name: -

Network Information:

Workstation Name: -

Source Network Address: X.X.X.X (IP address one off nodes from the cluster)

Source Port: 54096

Detailed Authentication Information:

Logon Process:

Authentication Package: NTLM

Transited Services: -

Package Name (NTLM only): -

Key Length: 0*

BR
Aleksei

Answer (score 0):

A null SID may occur when the username specified in a logon attempt does not correspond to a valid account.

https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4625

Comment: Greg, thank you for your answer. But, I don't understand what is the reason that NODE003 trying to login to NODE002.

Comment: The source was a process or application on that other node. You would need to review the data on that node to determine which process.

Comment: i would suggest my powershell script https://github.com/djdomi/Windows-Dos-Batch-Powershell/blob/master/log_security_failed_logon.ps1 if you want a mail about this